# C++ vector: upcasting subclasses to a superclass

Tags: c++, vector

How to upcast the vectors in my subclasses to superclass so that I can just use one pointer to modify and browse through the objects in the vectors? Thank you in advance!

```
class S { ... };

class A : public S { ... };
class B : public S { ... };
class C : public S { ... };

int main(){
  vector<A> aVec;
  A a;
  a.addList(aVec, ...some attributes...); //add objects into aVec using a function in class S
  a.addList(aVec, ...some attributes...);

  vector<B> bVec;
  B b;
  b.addList(bVec, ...some attributes...); //add objects into bVec using a function in class S

  vector<C> cVec;
  C c;
  c.addList(cVec, ...some attributes...); //add objects into cVec using a function in class S


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<S>>` and create your objects like `std::unique_ptr<S>(new A)` and store them in the vector as appropriate.

Using `unique_ptr`s not just raw pointers will ensure your objects are appropriately destructed just like they would be if they were directly stored in the `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a `vector<S*>`, and insert elements of type `A*`, `B*` or `C*` into it.

In c++ if you want to use polymorphism, you have to do it by pointers. Unfortunately this is not very highlighted in any manual. I was myself surprised that it works this way.

Comment: There is no good alternative in this case, though in general polymorphism can be achieved through other means such as overloading and templates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are asking directly.

The reason is that a derived class instance can have more members than the base class instance. Thus the three derived classes and the base can all be different as memory layout and no single pointer type can handle that.

One possible solution is to add one level of indirection and just manage pointers to instances instead of instances. That way you can even create an heterogeneous vector where each element can be referring to any of the subclasses.

Commonly it's considered a good idea to use "smart pointer" instead of raw pointers to take care of lifetime issues to avoid leaks or use of objects after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given as comments to the following example. You see at the end of the code how to compile it. (The `compile-command`.) Please, next time give a working example of what you have!

An alternative to the following code is to use template algorithms for your vectors.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct S {
public:
    int el;
    virtual ~S() {}; // you need this to be polymorphic
};

struct A : public S {
public:
    int elA;
    virtual ~A() {};
};
struct B : public S {
    virtual ~B() {};
};

int main(){
    /**
         To write generic algorithms you normally use pointers to objects
         of the base class and down-cast when you store elements.
     */
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<S> > aVec;

    A a;
    a.el = 2;
    a.elA = 3;

    /**
         If you do not want to keep local storrage for the objects you
         normally use the heap for the objects and store smart
         pointers with reference counting for the objects in the vector.
         Note, shared_ptr are C++11.
             Note also, that normally you should avoid to use `new` explicitly.
     */
    aVec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<S>(dynamic_cast<S*>(new A(a))));
    aVec.push_back(std::shared_ptr<S>(dynamic_cast<S*>(new A(a))));

    /**
         You can then treat the objects in the vector like such of type S:
     */
    std::for_each(aVec.begin(),aVec.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<S> p) { std::cout << "el=" << p->el << "\n"; });

    /**
         You recover the vector elements by back-casting them to the type A*.
         But, test the recovered pointer.
         If the cast fails (because the element was not really of type A) then dynamic_cast delivers a null-pointer.
     */
    std::for_each(aVec.begin(),aVec.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<S> p) {
            A* pa = dynamic_cast<A*>(p.get());
            if(pa) {
                std::cout << "elA=" << pa->elA << "\n";
            }
        });
}

/**
Local Variables:
compile-command: "g++ --std=c++11 test.cc -o test.exe; ./test.exe"
End:
 */
```

If you are interested you can also have a look at the answer to "Why can't I assign a `vector<Apple*>` to a `vector<Fruit*>`?" in http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html . Your question is quite similar. For you it is `vector<Apple>` to `vector<Fruit>` causing the same problem.